# how to call a method(in activity(A)) from another activity(B) to work on that activity(A)?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activity. one is main activity("A") and another is a Dialog("B") and it("B") is also an activity. when I click "ok" on dialog("B") it("B") will be closed and *a method will be called in activity "A"* and **the method will work on activity("A")**. How can I call a method from activity("B") to work on activity("A)?? I am learning android studio and don't know much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to call a method which is in Activity A from Activity B. First of all, the interactivity communications are not advisable the way you have portrayed it.

But, there are ways you can achieve what you have asked.

1. **Start Activity For Result**

If the Activity B is started from Activity A using StartActityForResult,

```
 //Activity A

 val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1001) //Any request code
```

You can get the result in onActivityResult callback on activity A.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data:Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 1001 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        callYourMethod()
}
```

2. **Pass a boolean in the intent. (This is kind of a hack)**

When you click ok on the dialog in Activity B, call activity A by passing a boolean value in the intent.

```
 val intent = (this, ActivityA::class.java)
 val bundle = Bundle()
 bundle.putBoolean("KEY", true)
 startActivity(intent, bundle)
```

And in Activity A's onCreate method, get the bundle from intent, and if it is true, then call the method.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val isTrue = intent.getBooleanExtra("KEY", false) //false is default value
        if(isTrue) 
          callYourMethod()
    }
```

There's also another way to communicate between classes like from adapter to Activity, fragment to activity etcetera using `Interface`. But, I hope the above-mentioned steps will help you for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command pattern here. You can create an interface in your `ActivityB`

Eg:

```
    public interface OnYourButtonClickListener
    {
        void performActionOnClick(Params...);
    }
```

Now, Make your `ActivityA` implement the above interface and override the method in the interface in your `ActivityA`, i.e. override `performActionOnClick`.

Now, Make sure to receive the context of the calling activity (where you have implemented the interface) in your `ActivityB` and cast it to your interface type so that you can call the action which you want to perform.

To read more about this pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern